# Increasing CPU and memory usage in a Spark Structured Streaming application

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, memory-leaks, amazon-emr, spark-structured-streaming

**Problem Formulation**

I am currently developing an application using Spark Structured Streaming through the PySpark API. I am hosting this application in an AWS EMR cluster.

The main flow of my application is the following:

1. Read from a Kafka Topic
2. Transform each micro-batch, using forEachBatch, as follows:
   2. Perform simple and stateless aggregations (groupBy + count).
   4. Write the micro-batch to a Kafka topic

While the app is running, I observed a constant increase in host's CPU and memory usage, under constant load, as seen in the following graphs.
[image: CPU increase]
[image: Memory Increase]

This behavior is consistent across runs. When restarting the application, CPU usage falls to the starting point and then consistently increases.

**Questions**
I have read about the possibility that Garbage Collector is responsible for this increase, but I believe that there is a lot of memory space available.

I plan to add complexity in my application logic, so I am worried that this behavior will have a severe impact on the application's runtime.

My questions are:
What is the cause behind this behavior?
Can I configure Spark to better handle my usecase?

Comment: I am facing the exact same problem (also running Structured Streaming with Pyspark, but on Kubernetes instead of EMR). Have you found a solution to your problem and can share it perhaps?